# Storing formattable string resource in string.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-resources

How do I store a formattable string resource in `res/value/string.xml` so that it does not break my `R.java`? Presently I simply have the following but it's not working.

```
<string name="format_able">This is a formatable string resource with %s and %s as place holders</string>
```

But eclipse does not redline it. So it took me hours to figure that this was the reason my R was not being generated. So how do I escape the `%s`?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

Comment: have you tried a `Project > Clean`

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer finally at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling specifically

```
 <string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>
```

I was missing `1$`, `2$`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the "%" character for its HTML codification. For example to insert "..." you have to write the code

```
"&#8230;"
```

The code for "%" is

```
"&#37;"
```

You can see it in this page: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: may you clarify your answer?